# nvd3 Box Plot with Dates

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

I'm trying to get a box plot going where my Y axis is going to be Dates. I have tried to strip down to the bare minimum and I only see "No Data Available".

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dLBxEU?p=preview)

```
$scope.data = [{
                   label: "Sample A",
                   values: {
                      Q1: new Date(),
                      Q2: new Date()
                   }
                 },
               ];
```

I just want to see some Dates and I can go forward from there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify `Q3` too.

```
$scope.data = [{
     label: "Sample A",
     values: {
         Q1: new Date(),
         Q2: new Date(),
         Q3: new Date()
     }
}];
```

It's because nvd3 [boxplot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_plot) use the first quartile, the mediam (Q2), and the third quartile.

Here is a working [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/TF1wvfdND7kplvcIqx1b?p=preview)

Comment: So we are forced to only use "Q1","Q2" and "Q3"?
It wont work if I replace it with "A", "B","C"